# Run with debug prompts Extension in Visual Studio Code

Tags: java, c, visual-studio-code

I am still particularly new to Visual Studio Code and just starting to learn coding. When i press run on vs code, it prompts me to a new Get Started page. How do I ensure that I can run the program normally?

I tried to install some extensions and was hoping that it would run and execute the output normally. However, i am very confused as to why it prompts to a new Getting Started page instead.

Comment: VS Code is not very beginner friendly as it often requires manual configuration. If you want to compile C code use something "out of the box" like eclipse CDT

Comment: If you're learning C, learning a build system on top of that is going to be daunting. Consider a more integrated, ready to run tool like Visual Studio Community.

Answer (score 0):

Whether the [Java extension pack](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=vscjava.vscode-java-pack) is installed. The encoding package deployment environment can be installed directly.

[image]

It would be better to refer to the [official documentation](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/java/java-tutorial) to start writing Java in vscode.